# NI-MH battery charger using MAX712

Tags: battery-charging, nimh

I don't belong to electrical engineering but I am trying to develop a intelligent Ni-Mh battery charger for one of my project. I am using [MAX712](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX712-MAX713.pdf) battery charging management IC. Reason behind that is:

1. It's available in DIP format so I can give a try on Zero PCB easily.
2. Cost factor.

My aim is to build a efficient charger that can find out when my battery is fully charged and cut out the charging after that and at the same time didn't harm the battery life (I find out from some of the forum that fast charging harms the battery life, though I cannot provide the link but I had read somewhere.)

I am not sure about the charging method. As per my study of MAX712 datasheet, there are generally 2 methods to find out when battery is fully charged:

1. \$\dfrac{dV}{dt}\$ (using the rate of change of voltage)
2. \$\dfrac{dT}{dt}\$ (using the rate of change of temperature of batteries)

I had prepared a schematic using the available resources on net and from the datasheet. Can any one help me to find out the best possible practice of charging Ni-Mh batteries using MAX712? I have to charge eight 1.2V Ni-Mh batteries. I am including my schematics for battery charging. Need help to be verify this and a possible way to provide trickle charging.

[image: Schematic]